# How can wireless cards act as wireless hostpots?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a PC with Intel's wireless card. I assume that the card is mainly meant for using WiFi connections but how is that able to create a Wi-Fi hotspot? I'm interested in knowing what actually happens internally when I turn on Wireless hotspot in the operating system, lets say, Ubuntu or Windows? Is the same strategy goes with smart phones such as that of Apple or Samsung?

Comment: I think the explanation depends on why you think they _couldn't_ act as access points?

Comment: The card contains firmware that implements both the access point (AP, what you call "hotspot") part of the 802.11 WLAN protocol, as well as the client protocol. Your computer contains a chunk of software that uses the card's firmware for the client protocol (normal case), and another chunk of software that uses the card's firmware for the AP protocol. The latter gets turned on when you click on "Wireless Hotspot". (Of course, there's lots of details I skipped over). Very old WLAN cards only have client firmware.

Comment: @dirkt should be an answer, its a good question that has never been asked I believe